# Do two sentences below have the same meaning?

Tags: grammar, phrases

the voltage is higher than the amplifier required

---

the voltage is higher than it was required by amplifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is not grammatical.

"the voltage is higher than was required by the amplifier" has the same meaning as your first sentence.